# Is one leg being smaller than the other affecting my squat?

Tags: strength-training, stronglifts, knee-pain, lower-body-strength

So I’ve been weightlifting for about 6 months now and have osgood schlatters disease (OSD) in my left leg for about 4 years and never notice it anymore only when I bend my knees into a deep position. I’m trying to work on my squat strength but I’ve noticed my left thigh is about 3cm smaller in circumference than my right and everytime I squat heavy I’m struggling to hit depth and my right knee (good leg) gets sore. What should I do to improve this?

Comment: I'd start by reviewing your technique. Are you excessively breaking at the knees to hit depth vs breaking at the hips?

Comment: I think I'm excessively breaking at my hips more than knees and I really struggle to hit depth 90° or less.